# Return to main menu when clicking on button

Tags: android, button, android-studio

When I click on the menu button I want to return to the main menu, activity with which the app starts with. What must follow the app.mobiledevicesecurity part? I thought it must be the starting class name? I am new to android studio development. Any help will be appreciated.

Logcat details:

```
09-01 19:02:04.755    1988-1988/app.mobiledevicesecurity E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.mobiledevicesecurity, PID: 1988
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=app.mobiledevicesecurity.MainActivity }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1781)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
            at app.mobiledevicesecurity.Result$2.onClick(Result.java:46)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Result.java:

```
package app.mobiledevicesecurity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Result extends Activity
{
    private static Button playbtn;
    private static Button menubutton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        OnClickPlayButtonListener();
        OnClickMenuButtonListener();
        TextView textResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textResult);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int score = b.getInt("score");
        textResult.setText("You scored" + " " + score + " for the quiz.");
    }

    public void OnClickPlayButtonListener() {
        playbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        playbtn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("app.mobiledevicesecurity.Quiz");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void OnClickMenuButtonListener() {
        menubutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menubtn);
        menubutton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("app.mobiledevicesecurity.MainActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }


}
```

Any suggestions with what I must replace the MainActivity text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

this works for me...